# Maximize Sum of Matrix Row/Col Intersections

Tags: algorithm, matrix, linear-algebra, mathematical-optimization

I'm seeking an algorithm better than brute force.

Given an M x N matrix of integers, identify the set of rows/columns such that the sum of all elements at their intersections is maximized.

Below is an example case and solution.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to explain what you mean by brute force. To solve the example, you only need to compute 4 sums, and choose the largest one. That doesn't seem so bad.

Comment: @user3386109 Brute force would be trying every subset of columns against every subset of rows. Which is `2^(n+m)` combined subsets. It isn't obvious how this should reduce to 4 sums in the example.

Comment: @btilly Column 2 has no negative values, so column 2 can be unconditionally chosen. That leaves only two columns, each can be chosen or not, resulting in 4 possible column combinations. For each column combination, only the rows that provide a positive contribution to the sum should be chosen.

Comment: For example, if column 1 is rejected, and column 3 is chosen, then the column combination is `(C2,C3)`. (Note that C2 is always chosen). For that combination, row 1 contributes nothing, and row 2 would contribute -3, so they are rejected. Rows 3 and 4 both contribute 4, so they are selected, and the sum of 8. The sum for `(C2)` is 13, `(C1,C2)` is 18, and `(C1,C2,C3)` is 11. So the answer is 18.

Comment: @btilly The time complexity is `O(m*2^(m-1)) = 3*2^2 = 12` which is a heck of a lot better than `O(2^(n+m)) = 2^(3+4) = 128`. But it's still brute force. So my comment to the OP was simply to ask if the OP had put any effort at all into the problem. (Note: the -1 in `m*2^(m-1)` is due to the fact that column 2 can be unconditionally chosen. There are other ways to nibble at the edges of the problem to improve run time performance. But the algorithm is ultimately  and unavoidably exponential as you pointed out in your answer.)

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to model it as a linear program with binary variables and then use an integer linear programming (ILP) package to obtain optimal values for the variables.

Suppose the array of returns is given by x, where x<sub>ij</sub> is the return in row i and column j.

First define the binary variables.

r<sub>i</sub> equals 1 if row i is selected, else equals 0, for each i

c<sub>j</sub> equals 1 if column i is selected, else equals 0, for each j

e<sub>ij</sub> equals 1 if both row i and column j are selected, else equals 0, for each i,j pair

The objective (function) and constraints are as follows::

max ∑<sub>i</sub>∑<sub>j</sub>x<sub>i,j</sub>e<sub>ij</sub>

subject to:

2*e<sub>ij</sub> ≤ r<sub>i</sub> + c<sub>j</sub> for each i,j pair

e<sub>ij</sub> ≥ r<sub>i</sub> + c<sub>j</sub> - 1 for each i,j pair for which x<sub>ij</sub> < 0

The first set of constraints prevents e<sub>ij</sub> from equalling 1 unless both r<sub>i</sub> and c<sub>j</sub> equal 1.

The second set of constraints force e<sub>ij</sub> to equal 1 if both both r<sub>i</sub> and c<sub>j</sub> equal 1. These constraints are not required for i,j pairs for which x<sub>ij</sub> ≥ 0 as optimality will force those values to 1 when both r<sub>i</sub> and c<sub>j</sub> equal 1.

The constraints would be expressed in standard form as follows.

2*e<sub>ij</sub> - r<sub>i</sub> - c<sub>j</sub> ≤ 0 for each i,j pair

-e<sub>ij</sub> + r<sub>i</sub> + c<sub>j</sub> ≤ 1 for each i,j pair for which  x<sub>ij</sub> < 0

Comment: A stronger formulation would replace 2*eij ≤ ri + cj by eij ≤ ri and eij ≤ cj.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is NP hard.

We can see that by reducing the maximum clique problem to it. Take a graph `G` of size `n`. Turn it into an `n x n` symmetric matrix by turning each vertex into a column and row, with a 1 for each edge, 1s down the diagonal, and `-n` everywhere else. Solving your problem now finds the square of the size of the maximum clique.

Finding whether a clique of size `k` exists is one of Karp's 21 NP-complete problems. Finding tbe size of the maximum clique is NP-hard. So your problem is NP-hard.